# Movement between September visa bulletin and the current visa bulletin for October by USCIS

Tags: usa, visa

What are the movement/changes to take note of between September visa bulletin and the current visa bulletin for October published by the USCIS and how that affects immigrants and potential immigrants?

Comment: This is too specific and has a time component. That is, the question and any answers will only be good for a month or two. Vote to close.

Comment: @mkennedy yet the close vote reason is "too broad"; how can a question be both too specific and to broad?

Comment: I saw that...but the other close reasons made less sense.